# Не могу передать переменную из Activity во Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть два фрагмента. В первом фрагменте есть интерфейс, через который я передаю переменную в активити (передается как положено), а уже в активити я пытаюсь передать эту переменную через `bundle` во второй фрагмент и отобразить, но получаю `FATAL EXCEPTION`.

Интерфейс в активити:

```
override fun subChapterItem(chapterId: Int) {
    SubChapterBottomSheet.newInstance(chapterId)
    val subChapterBottomSheet = SubChapterBottomSheet()
    subChapterBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, SubChapterBottomSheet.SubChaptersTag)
}
```

Код во фрагменте, в который пытаюсь передать переменную:

```
companion object {

    const val SubChaptersTag = "sub_chapters_tag"
    private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): SubChapterBottomSheet {
        return SubChapterBottomSheet().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val sectionNumber = arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) // Здесь выходит `FATAL EXCEPTION`
}
```

**UPD**

```
Process: com.example, PID: 14217
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.example.ui.fragment.FirstSubChapterBottomSheet.onCreate(FirstSubChapterBottomSheet.kt:48)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:270)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1173)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
```

Comment: Запустите дебаг функции subChapterItem() и посмотрите есть ли в subChapterBottomSheet значение, что вы "передали". Конечно нет, нельзя передать что-то в один обьект, а ожидать что это появится в другом.

Comment: И как быть? Как правильно передать из активити в BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы свой FATAL EXCEPTION, проблема может быть совсмем не там, где вы думаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь вы создаете инстанс своего фрагмента, но ничему не присваиваете его. Ниже строчкой вы снова создаете инстанс своего фрагмента, но уже совсем без аргументов.

```
override fun subChapterItem(chapterId: Int) {
    **SubChapterBottomSheet.newInstance(chapterId)**
    val subChapterBottomSheet = SubChapterBottomSheet()
    subChapterBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, SubChapterBottomSheet.SubChaptersTag)
}
```

Должно быть примерно так

```
override fun subChapterItem(chapterId: Int) {
        val subChapterBottomSheet = SubChapterBottomSheet.newInstance(chapterId)
        subChapterBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, SubChapterBottomSheet.SubChaptersTag)
    }
```

Я думаю проблема в этом.

Comment: Ну я как раз таки передаю переменную в инстанс, но, как и говорит @Спицко Дмитрий, я потом просто вызываю новый фрагмент с пустым инстансом

Comment: Ну я вам тоже самое и написал. :)

Comment: Ну необходимо больше информации. В том коде который вы предоставили вроде бы все хорошо, за исключением того что я описал.

Comment: @McDaggen, если ошибка изменилась, задайте новый вопрос. Если все та же, добавьте ее в этот вопрос.

Comment: Всё, справился! Всё заработало

Answer (score 1):

```
 override fun subChapterItem(chapterId: Int) {
    SubChapterBottomSheet.newInstance(chapterId)
    val subChapterBottomSheet = SubChapterBottomSheet()
    subChapterBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, SubChapterBottomSheet.SubChaptersTag)
}
```

У вас в коде серьезная логическая ошибка. Строка `SubChapterBottomSheet.newInstance(chapterId)` создает фрагмент с нужными вам значениями, но никуда его не сохраняет. Потом в  `val subChapterBottomSheet = SubChapterBottomSheet()` вы создаете еще один фрагмент но уже без использования arguments и задания значения полю. Этот "неверный" фрагмент вы прикрепляете и получаете не тот результат, который хотите. Исправить просто - сохранять в переменную надо то, что возвращает getInstance, а вызов конструктора для фрагмента вообще никогда не использовать. Поставьте ему уровень доступа private, чтобы  случайно не использовать в другом месте

```
class SubChapterBottomSheet private constructor() : Fragment(){
}
```

Comment: Дмитрий, вопрос. А система может создавать инстанс фрагмента если будет приватный конструктор?

Comment: Если во фрагменте создавать приватный конструктор, вы получите краш при пересоздании фрагмента. Т.к. система не сможет найти нужный конструктор для пересоздания

Comment: Дмитрий, проблема в том, что работаю с `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, как же его вызвать если конструктор private?

Comment: @Сергей Бувака возможно вы правы, я обычно пользуюсь retainInstance и в таком случае так сделать можно. Без него может быть проблемно...

Comment: @McDaggen Это не ваш фрагмент, с ним такой фокус провести не выйдет

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий Тогда как переменную мне передавать из активити?

Comment: @McDaggen как я и Сергей Бувака описали в ответах. Уберите вызов конструктора, а в переменную сохранять результат getInstance